How to resend the request to the server?
I use the following function to send a request to the server and receive a response.
   public interface TokenCheckCallback {
    void onResult(boolean token_exist);

    void onError(Throwable throwable);
}

        app.checkToken(app.appToken, new App.TokenCheckCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(boolean token_exist) {
            // Handle the result here
            if (token_exist) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                return;
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserLogin.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("SignInForm", "Dastyar");
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
            // Handle the error here
        }
    });


  public void checkToken(String token, TokenCheckCallback callback) {
    TokenModel token_row = new TokenModel();
    token_row.setToken(token);
    client.tokenCheck(token_row).enqueue(new Callback<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Boolean> call, @NonNull Response<Boolean> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.i("naderTag", "Success " + response + " - code=" + response.code());
                callback.onResult(Boolean.TRUE.equals(response.body()));
            } else {
                if (response.code() == 500){
                    // Attempt again
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Boolean> call, @NonNull Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e("naderTag", "Fail in Server:" + throwable);
            callback.onError(throwable);
        }
    });
}

I want the request to be sent again when the server response was not successful and the code 500 was received and this request should be repeated at least 2 times.
